# It is expected to get all the row from mysql but getting first one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get all values shown in a table from mysql but getting one . 
I want to get the rows of the mysql table at in the last table mentioned in the code

////////Here is a desc of no use --- blah for just posting this question / as i am getting an error msg for giving more details information about this question /////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here is the code:

```
   $sql = 'SELECT
           item_added
           FROM
           products_added
           ORDER BY id';

           $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

               if(mysqli_num_rows($results) < 1){
                   echo "No items";
                }else{
                  $new_sql    = 'SELECT
                                item_added,
                                quantity,
                                amount,
                                sum(amount) as items_total
                                FROM
                                products_added
                                where `username` = "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]).'"
                                ORDER BY id';

                        $resu =  mysqli_query($conn, $new_sql);

                    }
                        ?>
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Item</td>
                                        <td>Qyt</td>
                                        <td>Price</td>
                                        <td>Action</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php 
                                    while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($resu)){
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['item_added'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td><a class=\"remove-from-cart\" href=\"\"><i class=\"fa fa-times\"></i></a></td>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Comment: Have you run your query directly on mysql? Maybe you just have 1 selected record there?

Comment: Why do you have two queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its because you're using an aggregate function SUM() without a GROUP BY.  In the $new_sql query, try adding "GROUP BY item_added" right before "ORDER BY id".

Comment: IT works..Could u plz explain how it worked and when it should be used..Actually i am new to php.Thanks

Comment: When you use SUM() (or any other aggregate function), you’re telling MySQL to group data.  If you don’t include a GROUP BY, then it will group all rows into one row, which is why you would have only seen one row.

Another way you could have fixed it is by just removing “, sum(amount) as items_total“, since you’re not using items_total and then MySQL wouldn’t try to do any grouping/aggregation.